# C++ | main function error | beginners

Tags: c++, program-entry-point

I'm totally new with c++ and I'm using eclipse.

but... I don't know why I get this error at the main function:

> ERROR: ::main must return int

My code is:

```
void main()
{
char a;
while (a!='q')
{
    string ln = "enter option: ";
    cout<< ln;

    switch(a)
    {
    case 1:
        if (a=='1')
            func1();
        break;
    case 2:
        if (a=='2')
            break;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in C++, the `main` function must have a return type of `int`.

Your version with a return type of `void` is incorrect and is being correctly rejected by your compiler.

Just change the declaration from

```
void main()
```

to

```
int main()
```

There is an alternative form that allows you to process arguments passed on the command line to your program. It looks like this:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

but when you're just learning C++ and trying to print "hello world" on the screen, this is probably not something you need to worry about. You'll get there eventually.

And consider updating the book you're using to learn C++, too. If it's getting the function signature of the entry point wrong, what other more complicated things might it also be getting wrong?! No point in learning the language wrong the first time around. A list of suggested books is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Wait a second, you min Main cant be a void type function? i`m pretty sure i`ve seen  void main() before

Comment: @Bogdan: That would not be correct C++. Other languages might use `void` as the type of the main function, like C#. Additionally, some very old compilers supported `void main`, but it was never standard or correct.

Comment: You'll see it often enough, usually in bad text books, and some compilers will even allow it, but it's still wrong.

Comment: Thank you, you made it clear,  sry for keep asking but i want to learn things the good way :), i learned python 1 semster at university and c seems easy now beside pointer thing, but the differnces ar not many but still pretty big :p
i work on a 2 array sort than merg them stil sorted :) thanks

Comment: The C standard permits return types other than int but few compilers actually support that. It's possible that you have seen C code with a void main.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your `void main()` to `int main()`.

You can't have a main function without any return in C++.

Answer (score 2):

```
char a;
while (a!='q')
```

You are comparing an uninitialized variable with the letter q. Reading from an uninitialized variable invokes undefined behavior. If you're unlucky, `a!='q'` might be false. Change `char a;` to `char a = 0;` (or any other non-q value) or replace the while loop with a do-while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The return type should be `int`:

`int main (void)`

`int main (int argc, char *argv[])`